# Have installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and have 2 problems

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu recently alongside WinXP & Robolinux and whenever I start my computer I don't have the option to boot to the other systems. When the computer starts it goes straight to Ubuntu without giving me an OS selection menu.

Also when turning on the PC I get the message:

```
d-sub out of range 46.5khz/43khz
```

and then:

```
d-sub no signal entering power save mode shortly
```

I then need to put the Ubuntu install CD I made into the cd drive before I get the Ubuntu login screen. After logging in Ubuntu works and I can remove the cd.

Any ideas on what I can do to get the os selection option at start up? And what about the d-sub message? any help is appreciated

Comment: If you can boot to Ubuntu you can try : sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an older laptop or Desktop where you trying to do this.
In case this laptop/desktop is less than 5 yrs old - you might want to disable secure boot.
Make sure after that you run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Regarding your d-sub issue - I didn't encountered this but sharing what I found [googling](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19590163) and [this one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/when-the-computer-comes-onthe-monitor-says-d-sub/2a3eb02a-8180-4382-b00d-1f19bea94631?auth=1)